# Swift xcode horizontal line

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I wonder what the best way to create a horizontal line is?

I have a few labels / text and I would like to add a horizontal line between them. More or less like a

---

when using twitter bootstrap.

Right now I am using a UIview and setting it as 1 in height with a black background color. But I guess this isnt the best way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the way to do it in iOS. **UIView** is the class which represent something to be shown on the screen. Every UI component is direct or indirect descendant of **UIView**. So, you should use **UIView**.

UIView is backed by **CALayer** to render the content to screen. You could also use **CALayer**, **CAShapeLayer** or other layer classes to create a border. But, I would not recommend to use **CALayer** just to show a border  as it is simpler to use **UIView** with height of 1, on the top of that, you get some nice addition such as autolayout. If you use **CALayer**, you will have to set frame to layer at appropriate time when the view bounds change. It could also be tricky due to some intrinsic animation within CALayer.

Comment: Thanks, but does it matter how many UIViews I have?- when it comes to performance. Right now I have about 5-6 UIviews with a height of 1 and everyone just acts like a line

Comment: Yes, it matters (to performance) how many views/layers you have. But the thresholds for worrying about that are when you get up to hundreds or thousands of views onscreen, not a few.